# How to send and receive message in azure service bus queue with session id?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I want to know how to send and receive messages from service bus queue using session Id in .Net and Can anyone please summarize how the session in the service bus queue works? and I am a beginner for service bus and please provide if there is any link for easy understanding.

Comment: You can find plenty of information about the topic. Perhaps reading the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions) first would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you, Sean. It is Useful